# Very strange behavior with extremely simple plain C non-negative integer parser

Tags: c, parsing, null, printf, stdio

As part of a much larger piece of code, I've written a set of functions that scan a file, skip the whitespace and read any non-negative integers present into an array. The problem is that when the whitespace-skipping code is called, if I don't call printf(), with *any* argument, then the code fails to produce the correct output. I've isolated the problem to the eat_whitespace() function.

In my code I call fseek() and I've tried various variations equivalent to that function call, but, none of them has helped. I can compile my code with a `printf(NULL)` , but, that seems to be a huge kludge. In addition, I've experienced strange behavior wherein the working code that uses the kludge produces incorrect output, but, when executed again the output goes back to being correct. This might seem to point to my code not properly closing file handles, but it does, and I've verified that it does. I really don't know what the problem is.

```
//#define KLUDGE1
//#define KLUDGE2

int is_ws_char (char c) {
    char ws_chars[4] = {'\n', '\t', ' ', '\r'};
    int detected_ws_char = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (c == ws_chars[i]) {
            detected_ws_char = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(detected_ws_char);
}

int eat_whitespace(FILE *data) {
    char c;

    while (fread(&c, sizeof(c), 1, data) == 1) {
        //Problem lies with the following code...
        //Seems that you need, for some strange reason, to issue a 
        //printf for the code to work... 

#ifdef KLUDGE1
        printf(NULL);
#endif

        if (!is_ws_char(c)) {
#ifdef KLUDGE2
            printf(NULL);
#endif
            fseek(data, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
            return(NOT_WHITESPACE);
        }
    }
    return(END);
}
```

The expected result would be the number parsing code returning correct results. For, example, [this](https://pastebin.com/TsTkRExK) input should produce the following output, without having to use the printf(NULL) "fix" :

```
42
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
100
100
1001
2222
2002
3333
1
2
3
4
6
5
7
9
8
10
11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

When the printf(NULL) kludge isn't used, then the following incorrect output is generated :

```
42
12
22
32
42
52
62
72
82
92
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
100
1000
1001
2222
2002
3333
13
23
33
43
63
53
73
93
83
10
11
1
20
30
40
54
6
7
80
9
10
11
```

EDIT : I've broken out the number parsing functions into their own small test program which I'll paste below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define END -1
#define NOT_WHITESPACE -2
#define NOT_NUMBER -2
#define NUM_SIZE_EXCEEDED -3
#define MAX_NUM_SIZE 257
//#define DEBUG1
//#define DEBUG2
//#define KLUDGE1
#define KLUDGE2

int is_ws_char (char c) {
    char ws_chars[4] = {'\n', '\t', ' ', '\r'};
    int detected_ws_char = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (c == ws_chars[i]) {
            detected_ws_char = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(detected_ws_char);
}

int eat_whitespace(FILE *data) {
    char c;

    while (fread(&c, sizeof(c), 1, data) == 1) {

        //Problem lies with the following code...
        //Seems that you need, for some strange reason, to issue a printf to stdout, with *any* argument eg. NULL for
        //the code to work...   
#ifdef KLUDGE1
        printf(NULL);
#endif

        if (!is_ws_char(c)) {
#ifdef KLUDGE2
            printf(NULL);
#endif
            fseek(data, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
            return(NOT_WHITESPACE);
        }
    }
    return(END);
}

int eat_number(FILE* data) {
    char c;
    char number_string[MAX_NUM_SIZE];
    int num_size = 0;
    int number;
    int chars_read;
    int token_type; 
    token_type = eat_whitespace(data);
    int digit_detected = 0;
    char digits[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    if (token_type == END) {
        return(END);
    }
    while(1) {
        if (num_size >= MAX_NUM_SIZE) {
            return(NUM_SIZE_EXCEEDED);
        }
        chars_read = (int) fread((void *) &c, sizeof(char), 1, data);
        if (!chars_read) {
            return(END);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (digits[i] == c) {
                    digit_detected = 1;
                    number_string[num_size] = c;
                    num_size++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(digit_detected) {
                digit_detected = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                if (is_ws_char(c)) {
                    fseek(data, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
                    number_string[(num_size+1)] = (char) 0x0;
                    number = atoi(number_string);
                    return(number);
                }
                else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character : %c", c);
                    return(NOT_NUMBER);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int token_type = 0;

    int n1 = 0;

    char *input_file_name = (*(argv + 1));

    FILE *input_file = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");

    if (input_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file : %s\n", input_file_name);
        return(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        token_type = eat_whitespace(input_file);
        if (token_type == END) {
            fclose(input_file);
            return(0);
        } 
        else if (token_type == NOT_WHITESPACE ) {
            n1 = eat_number(input_file);
            switch(n1) {
                case NOT_NUMBER : {
                    fclose(input_file);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number...\n");
                    return(1);
                }
                case NUM_SIZE_EXCEEDED : {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Exceeded maximum size of number string, which is 255 characters...\n");
                    fclose(input_file);
                    return(1);
                }
                default : {
                    if (n1 >= 0) {
                        printf("%i\n", n1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown error parsing number...\n");
                        fclose(input_file);
                        return(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fclose(input_file);
            fprintf(stderr, "Uknown error skipping whitespace...\n");
            return(1);
        }       

    }

    fclose(input_file);

    return(0);
}
```

It may not be pretty, but you can compile it with eg. gcc -g -Wall -Wpedantic -O0 number_parser_test.c -o  number_parser_test

EDIT #2 : I've pasted the input to the small test program below. I don't know if the tabs will be preserved, why is why I linked to the same text on pastebin

```
42   1  2 3    4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  17 18      19  20
     00100 100  1001

    2222 2002
            3333




 1  2  3  4  6 5 7 9    8 10 11

00000001
02
0003
04
5
06
00007
8
09
010
000011
```

EDIT #3 : The smallest input that I can use to demonstrate the problem would be the first line of the above text, containing the number 42 and then the numbers 1 through 20 including spaces and tabs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199155/discussion-on-question-by-jdb2-very-strange-behavior-with-extremely-simple-plain).

Answer (score 3):

The primary problem with the code in the question (as of [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57843867/revisions)) is that the code that null terminates the string does so one character too far through the string, so there is garbage to be converted after the number that was isolated.  In the function `eat_number()`, the line:

```
number_string[(num_size+1)] = (char) 0x0;
```

writes one byte too late; you should have:

```
number_string[num_size] = '\0';
```

If you think about the almost degenerate case when you have `num_size == 1`, you need to put the null byte after the digit in `number_string[0]`, which is `number_string[1]` or `number_string[num_size]`.

This code shows how I debugged it — with print statements (commented out with `//` comments).  They pointed me in the right direction, especially the one `//fprintf(stderr, "cvt=[%s]", number_string);`.  I stripped out your comments and the sections marked as kludges before trying to debug the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define END -1
#define NOT_WHITESPACE -2
#define NOT_NUMBER -2
#define NUM_SIZE_EXCEEDED -3
#define MAX_NUM_SIZE 257

static int is_ws_char(char c)
{
    char ws_chars[4] = {'\n', '\t', ' ', '\r'};
    int detected_ws_char = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (c == ws_chars[i])
        {
            detected_ws_char = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return(detected_ws_char);
}

static int eat_whitespace(FILE *data)
{
    char c;

    while (fread(&c, sizeof(c), 1, data) == 1)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, "W(%d=%c)", c, c);
        if (!is_ws_char(c))
        {
            fseek(data, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
            return(NOT_WHITESPACE);
        }
    }
    return(END);
}

static int eat_number(FILE *data)
{
    char c;
    char number_string[MAX_NUM_SIZE];
    int num_size = 0;
    int number;
    int chars_read;
    int token_type;
    int digit_detected = 0;
    token_type = eat_whitespace(data);
    char digits[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    if (token_type == END)
    {
        return(END);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        if (num_size >= MAX_NUM_SIZE)
        {
            return(NUM_SIZE_EXCEEDED);
        }
        chars_read = (int) fread((void *) &c, sizeof(char), 1, data);
        //fprintf(stderr, "N(%d=%c)", c, c);
        if (!chars_read)
        {
            return(END);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (digits[i] == c)
                {
                    digit_detected = 1;
                    number_string[num_size] = c;
                    num_size++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (digit_detected)
            {
                digit_detected = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (is_ws_char(c))
                {
                    fseek(data, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
                    number_string[num_size] = '\0';
                    //number_string[(num_size + 1)] = (char) 0x0;
                    //fprintf(stderr, "cvt=[%s]", number_string);
                    number = atoi(number_string);
                    return(number);
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character : %c", c);
                    return(NOT_NUMBER);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int token_type = 0;

    int n1 = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *input_file_name = (*(argv + 1));

    FILE *input_file = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");

    if (input_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file : %s\n", input_file_name);
        return(1);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        token_type = eat_whitespace(input_file);
        if (token_type == END)
        {
            fclose(input_file);
            return(0);
        }
        else if (token_type == NOT_WHITESPACE)
        {
            n1 = eat_number(input_file);
            switch (n1)
            {
            case NOT_NUMBER:
                fclose(input_file);
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number...\n");
                return(1);

            case NUM_SIZE_EXCEEDED:
                fprintf(stderr, "Exceeded maximum size of number string, which is 255 characters...\n");
                fclose(input_file);
                return(1);

            default:
                if (n1 >= 0)
                {
                    printf("%i\n", n1);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown error parsing number...\n");
                    fclose(input_file);
                    return(1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fclose(input_file);
            fprintf(stderr, "Uknown error skipping whitespace...\n");
            return(1);
        }
    }

    fclose(input_file);

    return(0);
}
```

There are a large number of other issues with the code, but it appears that you are working under some rules which don't allow you to do the job using `fscanf()`, or the functions from `<ctype.h>` or `<string.h>`.  For the most part, I don't plan to dissect the code further because there appear to be these these requirements.

I do note that the loop to detect whether a character is a digit is unusual.  The C standard requires that the code set supports [10 sequential code points for the digits `'0'` to `'9'`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3), so you can safely use notations like this, regardless of code set:

```
char c = …;
int value;

if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    value = c - '0';
```

to convert the character in `c` to an integer `0`..`9` in `value`.  Or, if you can use the functions from `<ctype.h>`, then:

```
if (isdigit((unsigned char)c))
    value = c - '0';
```

where the cast is desirable if the compiler implements plain `char` as a signed type, which is normally the way it is done with Intel processors (x86, etc).  (See C11 [§7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>` ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1) for more information on the need to cast.)

Given the data file (no tabs; single line, with newline at the end):

```
42   1  2 3    4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  17 18      19  20
```

The output from the code above (without the debugging printing) is:

```
42
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

This is what is expected.  With the bug and debugging code in place, the output (from program `io37` compiled from `io37.c`) looks like:

```
$ io37 data
W(52=4)W(52=4)N(52=4)N(50=2)N(32= )cvt=[42?]42
W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(32= )cvt=[1?]1
W(32= )W(32= )W(50=2)W(50=2)N(50=2)N(32= )cvt=[2?]2
W(32= )W(51=3)W(51=3)N(51=3)N(32= )cvt=[3?]3
W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(52=4)W(52=4)N(52=4)N(32= )cvt=[4?]4
W(32= )W(53=5)W(53=5)N(53=5)N(32= )cvt=[5?]5
W(32= )W(54=6)W(54=6)N(54=6)N(32= )cvt=[6?]6
W(32= )W(55=7)W(55=7)N(55=7)N(32= )cvt=[7?]7
W(32= )W(56=8)W(56=8)N(56=8)N(32= )cvt=[8?]8
W(32= )W(57=9)W(57=9)N(57=9)N(32= )cvt=[9?]9
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(48=0)N(32= )cvt=[10?]10
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(49=1)N(32= )cvt=[11?]11
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(50=2)N(32= )cvt=[12?]12
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(51=3)N(32= )cvt=[13?]13
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(52=4)N(32= )cvt=[14?]14
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(53=5)N(32= )cvt=[15?]15
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(54=6)N(32= )cvt=[16?]16
W(32= )W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(55=7)N(32= )cvt=[17?]17
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(56=8)N(32= )cvt=[18?]18
W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(57=9)N(32= )cvt=[19?]19
W(32= )W(32= )W(50=2)W(50=2)N(50=2)N(48=0)N(10=
)cvt=[20?]20
W(10=
)$
```

This shows the bogus characters as `?`, though I encountered a variety of oddball characters in different versions of the code.  The `?` allows the code to appear to convert the numbers correctly.  The last output is not terminated by a newline, so my prompt (shown as `$`) appears after the `)`.

A slightly different version of the code had lines like:

```
(32= )(49=1)(49=1)(49=1)(49=1)(32= )cvt=[11H]11
(32= )(49=1)(49=1)(49=1)(50=2)(32= )cvt=[12H]12
(32= )(49=1)(49=1)(49=1)(51=3)(32= )cvt=[13H]13
```

which also converted OK (the `H` was not a digit), but showed the incorrect null termination problem more clearly.  One of the disadvantages of undefined behaviour is that it isn't predictable what will be in the extra location.

With the fix active but the debugging code in place, the corresponding section of the output looks like:

```
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(49=1)N(32= )cvt=[11]11
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(50=2)N(32= )cvt=[12]12
W(32= )W(49=1)W(49=1)N(49=1)N(51=3)N(32= )cvt=[13]13
```

The `cvt` strings are clearly pure-numeric now, and not subject to the whims of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it's an off-by-one error generated by :

```
number_string[(num_size+1)] = (char) 0x0;
```

Which should instead be :

```
number_string[num_size] = (char) 0x0;
```

jdb2